# ASP MVC - How to properly select each .Include() property of a Model from WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webapi

Having example Models like below:

```
class School
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
class Student
{ 
    int StudentID { get; set; }

    string StudentName { get; set; }
}
class Teacher
{ 
    int TeacherId  { get; set; }
    bool IsOldTeacher { get; set; }
}
```

I need to receive an object of School from the WebAPI and I want to prevent the `.Include(x => x.Students)` and `.Include(x => x.Teacher)` when selecting the School object from DB in order to minimize the object size sent back from the WebAPI, and need to instead select the Teacher and then select each including object at a time after receiving the Teacher object.

What are the best methods to select each including objects (in this case Students and Teacher) from the School object?

My idea is to select the School object first then loop through all the includeable properties from the School object and by using reflection and getting their type, maybe I can send a request for each one of the types to the API and receive the objects. However this doesn't seem to be the best approach. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, what you need is an [odata endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint). It allows to pass [odata queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) specifying filter, properties and child entities you want to retrieve. Following the second link check out `expand` option for including a child entity.

Example: get a school by id and include old teachers only

```sql
http://myserver/odata/School?$filter=ID eq 50&$expand=Teacher($filter=IsOldTeacher eq true)
```